# Keydown event for ajax is possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like also to ajax action when you click "enter", currently this only for the click of the mouse, one loaded plugin to select items (jquery.keynav.js). Anyone know how to do?

jQuery

```
var main = function () {
    var url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20xml%20where%20url%3D'http%3A%2F%2Frss.cnn.com%2Fservices%2Fpodcasting%2Fac360%2Frss.xml'%20AND%20itemPath%3D%22%2F%2Fchannel%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=?";

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        async: false,
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (json) {
            var titles = json.query.results.channel.item.map(function (item) {
                return item.title;

            });

            var urls = json.query.results.channel.item.map(function (item) {
                return item.origLink;

            });

            $(".container-list-podcast ul").append('<li>' + titles.join('</li><li>'));
            $(".container-list-podcast ul li").each(function (key, value) {
                var text = $(this).text();
                $(this).html('<a class="link-podcast" href="' + urls[key] + '">' + text + '</a>');
            });

            a = $('.nav_holder li a').keynav(function () {
                return window.keyNavigationDisabled;
            });


        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log(e.message);
        }
    });

}(jQuery);
```

...continue

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eYwX3/8/)

Comment: What are you trying to do? Call the `main` function on keydown event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use the keycode

```
$("#elementId").keypress(function (e) {
   if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      alert('Enter key pressed!');
      //TODO: call Ajax here 
    }
});
```

Comment: `else if (e.keyCode == 13) {

    $('.container-list-podcast').on('.selected', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.video').attr('src', this.href);
    });

}`

what's wrong?

Comment: .on function in jquery atach an event to object (http://api.jquery.com/on/) 
You want add an event when the users press enter key ?

Comment: currently in the plugin like this:
`else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    window.location = current.attr('href');
    e.preventDefault();
}`

must leave the same example. ".click" that operate normally

Comment: i don´t understand.Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/sjpuas/KVGkJ/1/  please create an example on jsfiddle